# Angular Material: MatTooltip large active area arround prevents timely hiding and access to below elements

Tags: angular-material

I have a menu of small menu items tightly packed together.
After upgrading to Material 14.0.5 the matTooltip appears to have an outer active area of about 3 mm outside its borders. In other words, the tool tip does not hide if I point mouse cursor outside the menu item/element and the pointer is still close to the tool tip - witin about extra 3mm outside the tool-tip borders. In my case the tool tip keeps covering the neighboring items and prevents accessing them if my cursor is close to the tool-tip. I would need to have the too-tip hide as soon as the cursor leaves its borders. It worked fine for me before the upgrade as there was no such area around the tool-tips. Is there a way to reduce the active area around the matTooltip to zero? I tried changing the margins and padding but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    margin: -4px !important;
}
```